# Command to verify if pulling variable from cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way/ a command that will verify when running a package that it is pulling a variable from a cursor?

I have a package that I am running a cursor that I run the statement manually and it pulls what I need.  I run the package and its not pulling a variable.

```
CURSOR dbvalue_cur  IS   
SELECT ABC_ACCOUNT_A, 
      ABC_ACCOUNT_B, 
      ABC_A_PREM_LOC, 
      ABC_A_SERV_CLASS, 
      ABC_B_PREM_LOC, 
      ABC_B_SERV_CLASS, 
      ABC_A_CUST_COUNT, 
      ABC_A_REP_CON, 
      ABC_B_CUST_COUNT, 
      ABC_B_REP_CON, 
      ABC_A_ASVC, 
      ABC_B_ASVC, 
      ABC_REV_IND
FROM DEF, ABC
WHERE utrglcl_code = ABC_glcl_code
 AND utrglcl_code  = d_GLCLASS_CODE;

dbValue            dbvalue_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN  
  d_returnFieldsJSON := '';
  
  U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.returnFieldsTable   := U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.emptyReturnFieldsTable;
  d_GLCLASS_CODE    := NVL(U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.getPageCacheValue('UTRGLCL_CODE'), 'NULL');
   
/*******************************************
 ** VALIDATION LOGIC START
 *******************************************/
Open dbvalue_cur;
FETCH dbvalue_cur INTO dbValue;
```

I tried running cursor statement manually.

Answer (score 0):

You said you ran that `SELECT` statement manually and it returned some rows. It means that `WHERE` clause made it happen. It looks as

```
WHERE utrglcl_code = ABC_glcl_code
  AND utrglcl_code = d_GLCLASS_CODE;
```

which means that `utrglcl_code` has to be equal to both `ABC_glcl_code` **and** `d_GLCLASS_CODE`.

We don't know value of `ABC_glcl_code` (you didn't post that piece of code), while
`d_GLCLASS_CODE` equals `NVL(U$_OL_PROPERTY_DB.getPageCacheValue('UTRGLCL_CODE'), 'NULL')`.

Are you sure that `getPageCacheValue` returned valid value? Looks strange, though; you're applying `NVL` function which - in case that `getPageCacheValue` returns `null` sets `d_GLCLASS_CODE` to `'NULL'`, a string.

If I were you, I'd check what's going on with these two variables. The simplest way to do that is to display them; enable serveroutput and then

```
<snip>
dbms_output.put_line('ABC_glcl_code  = ' || ABC_glcl_code);
dbms_output.put_line('d_GLCLASS_CODE = ' || d_GLCLASS_CODE);

Open dbvalue_cur;
FETCH dbvalue_cur INTO dbValue;
```

What do you see? What happens when you put values (that are displayed) into `select` statement's `where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right the question is about a way to check is there or not a row fetched from cursor. If that is the question then the answer is yes. There are cursor attributes (%FOUND, %NOTFOUND, %ROWCOUNT) that  can be processed in runtime.
A small sample code using cursor attributes:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare 
    CURSOR dbValue_cur IS
        SELECT * FROM emp WHERE DEPTNO = 10;
    dbvalue     dbValue_cur%ROWTYPE;
Begin
    OPEN dbValue_cur;
      Loop
          FETCH dbValue_cur INTO dbvalue;
          IF dbValue_cur%NOTFOUND THEN    -- %NOTFOUND and %FOUND could be checked to see if the row is fetched or not
              dbms_output.put_line('Cursor data not found');
              EXIT;
          ELSE 
              dbms_output.put('Cursor row number ' ||dbValue_cur%ROWCOUNT);  -- %ROWCOUNT if = 0 there is no data / if > 0 row number fetched
              dbms_output.put_line('  ***  ' || dbvalue.EMPNO || ' ' || dbvalue.ENAME || ' --> ' || dbvalue.JOB);
          END IF;
      End Loop;
    CLOSE dbValue_cur;
End;
/
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
Cursor row number 1  ***  7839 KING --> PRESIDENT
Cursor row number 2  ***  7782 CLARK --> MANAGER
Cursor row number 3  ***  7934 MILLER --> CLERK
Cursor data not found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.  */
```

... OR without IF statement - a bit shorter code

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare 
    CURSOR dbValue_cur IS
        SELECT * FROM emp WHERE DEPTNO = 10;
    dbvalue     dbValue_cur%ROWTYPE;
Begin
    OPEN dbValue_cur;
      Loop
          FETCH dbValue_cur INTO dbvalue;
          EXIT WHEN dbValue_cur%NOTFOUND;
          dbms_output.put_line('Cursor row number ' ||dbValue_cur%ROWCOUNT || '  ***  ' || dbvalue.EMPNO || ' ' || dbvalue.ENAME || ' --> ' || dbvalue.JOB);
      End Loop;
    CLOSE dbValue_cur;
End;
/
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
Cursor row number 1  ***  7839 KING --> PRESIDENT
Cursor row number 2  ***  7782 CLARK --> MANAGER
Cursor row number 3  ***  7934 MILLER --> CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.  */
```